# How to fill white background inside the edges of image , for background removal?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, canny-operator

### How To Add Color Inside The Edges - Python (OpenCV)

I am Trying to remove the background From this image ,
Partatily  i Succeed From the help of Internet,I created edge of image using canny,
But i want to add white background inside the object edge ([inside the object edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXMpe.png)) ,
For better Output

> This Is the code for Remove Background ,That i Created

[Inputed Image](https://www.pexels.com/fr-fr/photo/beau-homme-individu-modele-614810/)

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('img/aa.jpg')
original=img.copy()

l = int(max(5, 6))
u = int(min(6, 6))

edges = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (21, 51),3)
edges = cv.cvtColor(edges , cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

mask = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

edges = cv.Canny(edges,l,u)
edges = cv.dilate(edges, None)
edges = cv.erode(edges, None)

_,thresh=cv.threshold(edges,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY  + cv.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morphed = cv.morphologyEx(thresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

dilate=cv.dilate(morphed, None, iterations = 1) #change iteration

mask=dilate


(cnts, _) =cv.findContours(dilate, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in cnts:
    # (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(contour)
    if cv.contourArea(contour) < 2000:
        continue
    cv.drawContours(mask ,contour, -1, (255, 255, 255), 3)


result = cv.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=mask)
result[dilate==0] = (0,0,0)


img1=cv.resize(mask,(600,400))
cv.imshow(' Image', img1)
img=cv.resize(result,(600,400))
cv.imshow('Original Image', img)
cv.waitKey()
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCPdP.png)

Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV color space
- Apply color thresholding on the background color in hsv to create a mask
- Invert the mask
- Apply morphology to fill the holes and remove extraneous regions
- Use mask to make background of images white

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image and get dimensions
img = cv2.imread("man_face.jpeg")

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold using inRange
range1 = (50,0,50)
range2 = (120,120,170)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,range1,range2)

# invert mask
mask = 255 - mask

# apply morphology closing and opening to mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15,15))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

result = img.copy()
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("man_face_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("man_face_white_background.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir , You Help Me a Lot

Comment: It works for this image. Other images may need different thresholds, etc.